# Api data with async of Node.js and retrieving data make it sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Im needing help with a Node weather app I'm making. Im using Google API to get me the longitude and latitude of an address and feed this into the Dark Sky API to return the weather in a JSON format.

My issue is the that most of the time the weather API does the search before the google API has returned the longitude and latitude. I know why its doing it because of the async nature of Node. My question is how do i make this part sync instead?

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https')
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var lon;

var lat;

app.post('/', function(req,res,next){

var search = req.body.search;


function google(){

    var api = "API-KEY";

    var url = https.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${search}&key=${api}`, function(res3){

        var body = "";
        var googleResults;

        res3.on('data', function(data){
            body += data.toString();
        })

        res3.on('end', function(){

            googleResults = JSON.parse(body);
            //console.log(body);
            lat = googleResults.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            lon = googleResults.results[0].geometry.location.lon;
            console.log(search);
        })

    });

}


google();

//connectc to API URL()
var request = https.get(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/API-KEY/${lon},${lat}`, function(res2){

console.log(lon + " " + lat)
            var body = "";
            var weather;
            //Read the data
            res2.on('data', function(data){
                body += data.toString();

            })

            res2.on('end', function(){
                    //Parse the data
                     weather = JSON.parse(body);
                    //Print data
                    //console.log("test = " + weather.currently.temperature)
                    res.render('index', {
                        temperature: weather.currently.temperature,
                        humidity: weather.currently.humidity,
                        wind: weather.currently.windSpeed
                    });
            })

});



});
```

Comment: You cannot make it sync! One option is to call weather api only after google result is finished

Comment: You posted your API key in this post, it was removed in an edit, but it has still been publicly exposed. You should revoke it and re-issue a new key.

Comment: @Adam thanks I already have, should have double checked before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do, without restructuring your code too much, is to make `google()` take a callback function as an argument. Then you can use that callback function to trigger the call to dark sky.

```js
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https')
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var search = req.body.search;

  // Have google() take a callback function as an argument and
  // call that function with the data when it's done.
  function google(cb) {

    var api = "API-KEY";

    var url = https.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${search}&key=${api}`, function(res3) {

      var body = "";
      var googleResults;

      res3.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data.toString();
      })

      res3.on('end', function() {

        googleResults = JSON.parse(body);
        //console.log(body);
        lat = googleResults.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        lon = googleResults.results[0].geometry.location.lon;
        // Call the function here
        cb(lat, lon);
      })

    });

  }

  // Now use the callback to do your second request to darksky
  google(function(lat, lon) {
    //connectc to API URL()
    var request = https.get(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/API-KEY/${lon},${lat}`, function(res2) {

      console.log(lon + " " + lat)
      var body = "";
      var weather;
      //Read the data
      res2.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data.toString();

      })

      res2.on('end', function() {
        //Parse the data
        weather = JSON.parse(body);
        //Print data
        //console.log("test = " + weather.currently.temperature)
        res.render('index', {
          temperature: weather.currently.temperature,
          humidity: weather.currently.humidity,
          wind: weather.currently.windSpeed
        });
      })

    });
  }});


});
```

Comment: You posted your API key in this post, it was removed in an edit, but it has still been publicly exposed. You should revoke it and re-issue a new key.

Comment: Oh, he originally posted his API key when I copied it.

Comment: Oops, I reviewed your solution and didn't see that. Thanks.

Comment: @JordanS thank you worked perfectly, I've requested new api keys also. School boy error. Looking into callbacks in more details also.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the easiest or most approachable way of solving your problem, but I've been using the `await` keyword along with the `node-fetch` library for doing these kinds of requests.

Basically `node-fetch` works on Promises, meaning you can make a request using it, and use `.then()` to do something after the request is done. The `await` keyword turns all that nesting into sync-like code, meaning it's easier to read and mantain. Here's how your code would look like using them:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https')
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var lon;
var lat;

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  var search = req.body.search;
  async function google() {

    var api = "";
    var googleResults = await (await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${search}&key=${api}`)).json()

    lat = googleResults.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    lon = googleResults.results[0].geometry.location.lon;
    console.log(search)
  }
});


(async() => await google())();

//connectc to API URL()
var weather = await (await fetch(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/7c41453dc9e5976eecb6a38487427b58/${lon},${lat}`)).json();
console.log(lon + " " + lat)
res.render('index', {
  temperature: weather.currently.temperature,
  humidity: weather.currently.humidity,
  wind: weather.currently.windSpeed
});
```

The catch is that since `await` is part of ES6, you might need to use something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to run it on older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Utilize NodeJS's asynchronous nature here (using node-style callbacks, promises, etc.)

For example, just add a callback parameter to your `google` function and don't run your http request until after the callback is fired. For example, your google function could become the following, and then you call google and run the following code in the callback:

```
function google(callback){
    callback = callback || function() {}

    var api = "API-KEY";

    var url = https.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${search}&key=${api}`, function(res3){

        var body = "";
        var googleResults;

        res3.on('data', function(data){
            body += data.toString();
        })

        res3.on('end', function(){

            googleResults = JSON.parse(body);
            //console.log(body);
            lat = googleResults.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            lon = googleResults.results[0].geometry.location.lon;
            console.log(search);
            callback()
        })

    });

}

google(function() {
    //execute your request and subsequent calls and app logic here
})
```

NOTE: I recommend passing parameters or return the `lat` and `lon` in the callback as opposed to pullutting your global scope with `lat` and `lon`, but this would work nonetheless.